# How do I install freesteam?

Tags: 12.04, installation

While installing the freesteam software downloaded from the http://sourceforge.net/projects/freesteam/ which is the only steam table software for Ubuntu, I am getting following error:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libfreesteam1.

the description of package : 
python-freesteam , file name :python-freesteam_2.0_i386(1).deb
```

Please help me out as it is the only available opensource steam table software to be used by mechanical engineering student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get freesteam working on a fresh, clean Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit system, you can download the packages from 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/freesteam/files/freesteam/2.1/

First you should grab the 'libfreesteam1' deb file, then after that grab 'freesteam-gtk' deb file, then finally grab 'python-freesteam' deb file, if you want to be able to use freesteam from within Python language. After each download, the Ubuntu Softare Centre pops up, and you need to click 'install' and type in your password each time.

You can easily test this by searching for 'freesteam' from the main Ubuntu menu. A basic GUI will pop up allowing you to evaluate the steam properties you need.

If you want to try using freesteam from Python, there are some examples here:
http://freesteam.sourceforge.net/example.php

Comment: libfreesteam1 is not in Ubuntu software centre and not even on the link provided by u , and the python-freesteam need libfreesteam1 , thanks in advance

Comment: Are you not seeing libfreesteam1_2.0_i386.deb on that list? It's here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/freesteam/files/freesteam/2.0/libfreesteam1_2.0_i386.deb

Comment: even after doing all this giving the message : dependency not satisfiable libpython2.6(>=2.6) even after installing python2.7 python2.7-dev plz help thanks in advance

Comment: Ah ok, so the Python dependency is also a (separate) problem. I have given another answer to the question based on a complete local compile of the code, hope it works for you.

Comment: I changed the directions above and tested on a new clean Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit system. If you have a 64-bit system, you will need to build your own code, see other answer to this question in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The version of freesteam that's hosted on SF.net was built with linkage to Python 2.6, but Python 2.7 is used on current Ubuntu 12.04. This means that, at least until a new version is released, you need to build your own copy of freesteam locally. Instructions from the freesteam README.txt for Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion scons libgsl0-dev python-dev swig ipython python-matplotlib
svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/freesteam/code/trunk freesteam
cd freesteam
scons
sudo scons install
```

To remove, you will need to look for freesteam files in /usr/local/{lib,bin,include} and /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.

Comment: i did run the above steps but how to launch the free steam i am a newbie in ubuntu plz help